# Can i change the src of a img to a video src and back?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a stream which runs only over the `<img>` Tag and would like to give the opportunity to watch three different videos on the same page, using the same space. So that instead of the `<img>` stream, there is than a `<video>`. Its supposed to work with buttons. So that the buttons change the source of the img into a video.

I tryed several things that didnt work. Currently im stuck with this:

This unfortunatly doesnt work, i dont know what to change since i just started with programming. (I also dont really know js, so i dont know if it is ok or not, since i didnt write it.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Livestream</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button data-video-url="/path/to/my/video/orstream"></button>
            <button data-video-url=""></button>
            <button data-video-url=""></button>
            <button data-video-url=""></button>
        </div> 
        <img id="player" src="mystreamsource" alt="Livestream" width="80%"> -->!originaly it was a video tag
    </body>
</html>

<script>
function swapVideo() {
    player.src = this.getAttribute("data-video-url");
    player.load();
    player.play();
  }

  var videoPlayButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button"),
    player = document.getElementById("player");

  for (var i=0; i<videoPlayButtons.length; i++){
    videoPlayButtons[i].addEventListener('click', swapVideo);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Why would an image tag support video? Show/Hide a video tag if you need to use video

Comment: I agree with @mplungjan. They are different tags for a reason. You can use hide() and show() methods via jQuery to show different videos on button click.

Comment: @KomalR It didnt work over the video tag, i actually dont know my self why, but everytime i tried it didnt show up. Maybe because its a livestream                           Both of you thanks very much the JQuery hide() show() worked.

Answer (score 0):

This process is a lot simpler than you might think, all we need to do is replace the outerHTML name. from img to video and then add a source element to it also.

```
function swapItem() {
  document.getElementById("player").outerHTML = 
  document.getElementById("player").outerHTML.replace('img',"video");
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  var source = document.createElement('source');
  source.src = 'movie.mp4';
  source.type = 'video/mp4';
  var player = document.getElementById('player');
  video.src = 'http://www.example.com';
  player.appendChild('source');
}
```

this is an example of how you could turn the image element into a video element.

I haven't tested this myself, so it may not work, but its the best that I could do with my knowledge.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I have to try it out

Comment: I tried it and found that due to the fact, that my link doesnt have a ".com" or such an extantion that it didnt work. But i really appreciate the effort.

Comment: @XesterMenia oh no. Sorry about that. I'm not a mastermind when it comes to javascript I'm pretty new also. Sorry I couldnt be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So i found a solution. And just incase someone else has this problem. This is how i did it:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#myVideo3').click(function(){
             $('#live').hide();
             $('#playerday').hide();
             $('#playerweek').hide();
             $('#playermonth').show();
         });
     });
```

This i've done for all my videos. Since i only have fours its easier that way.